# XCTestSuite of XCTestCase for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

I need to test a `UIViewController` which behavior depends on parameters given to it (controls are dynamically instantied in `viewDidLoad` based on a webservice call).

I would to be able to run the same `XCTestCase` derived class and inject testing the context. I thought I would use `XCTestSuite` for that but this is not the case as `XCTestSuite` is a suite of `XCTest` and not `XCTestCase`.

Basically I would like to do:

```
XCTestCaseSuite* suite = [[XCTestCaseSuite alloc] init];
for (Condition* condition in conditions) {
  MyTestCase* case = [[MyTestCase alloc] initWithCondition:condition];
  [suite addTestCase:case];
}
[suite runTest];
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted to do by looking at the code of
https://github.com/michalkonturek/XCParameterizedTestCase

Specifically I replicated the mechanism put in place in https://github.com/michalkonturek/XCParameterizedTestCase/blob/master/Source/XCParameterizedTestCase.m and was able to do what I wanted.

One drawback of this method is that all instances of the same test are reported the same way and there is no way to know which particular instance is failing for example. To circumvent that, I added dynamic class creation that inherits from the base `XCTestCase` class:

```
// create a dynamic class so that reporting is good
NSString* testClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Test", [condition.description capitalizedString]];
Class testClass = objc_allocateClassPair([MyTestCase class], [testClassName UTF8String], 0);
objc_registerClassPair(testClass);
```

Then you can instantiate each test case class with

```
XCTestCase *test = [[NSClassFromString(testClassName) alloc] initWithInvocation:invocation
                                                                    forCondition:condition];
```

I am going to try to implement this in a very generic `XCParameterizedTestCase` class...